# Does nornal distribution exist in coupling space?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X, Y$ be real-valued random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, and $N$ be a random variable under $(\Omega, F, P)$ which is normally distributed.(i.e. normal distribution exists in this space)

Suppose $(\Omega', F', P')$ is a coupling of $X$ and $Y$, does normal distribution exist on this space? Are there common conditions(for example on coupling or on $\Omega$) that make this true?

Comment: What's the precise definition of a coupling here?  Why does it require a new probability space, filtration, and probability measure when $X$ and $Y$ were already defined on the same probability space?

Comment: @user6247850 I follow the definition on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)